# find customers and their first payment

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables.

Accounts :

```
id
1
2
3
```

Customers :

```
id | account | email
76276 | 1 | test1@mail.com
143158 | 2 | test2@mail.com
143159 | 3 | test3@mail.com
```

Payments :

```
id | customer | date
285041 | 76276 | 2014-12-01 00:13:41
285042 | 76276 | 2014-12-01 00:15:55
285043 | 143158 | 2014-12-01 00:18:52
285044 | 143159 | 2014-12-02 12:21:47
```

I want to get all the accounts whose customer's first payment is between 2014-12-01 00:00:00 and 2014-12-01 23:59:59

I tried

```
SELECT a.id
FROM account a
JOIN customer c ON c.account = a.id
JOIN payment p ON p.id = (
    SELECT p.id 
    FROM payment p 
    WHERE p.customer = c.id 
    AND p.date BETWEEN '2014-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-12-01 00:59:59'
    ORDER BY date ASC 
    LIMIT 1
)
```

But this query runs for ages.. and i'm pretty sure this is not how I should join payment table. Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the first payment date by using `min()`.  Then just get the appropriate information:

```
select account
from customers c join
     payments p
     on p.customer = c.id
group by account
having min(p.date) >= '2014-12-01' and min(p.date)  < '2014-12-02';
```

Comment: I found another query doin the same thing based on `join select` but it took twice the time of yours. So i take yours, based on having clause. Thqnk you

Answer (score 0):

this query might be helpful.

```
SELECT a.id FROM accounts a
INNER JOIN Customers c ON c.account=a.id
INNER JOIN payments p ON p.customer=c.id
WHERE p.date BETWEEN '2014-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-12-01 23:59:59';
```

Comment: this query is not approriate. It will return a payment between the given dates, and it may not be the first payment of the customer.